# How to use a service to execute an expressJS app and insert data into sqlite3 database via apache on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, sqlite, apache, express, ubuntu

I have a service file that is executing an expressJS app via Apache2 on Ubuntu (21.04 GNU/Linux 5.11.0-1027-raspi aarch64).  The app.js file that is being executed contains code that will get data from a temperature sensor and insert the data in an sqlite3 database located in a directory on a mounted usb drive.  When I navigate to the expressJS directory and execute the app.js file from the console using `node app.js` the code will execute and insert the data into the database file without error.  However, when I start the service file, the code will execute the app.js file, but will throw the following error when trying to insert data into the database.

```
SQLITE_READONLY: attempt to write to a readonly database
```

I have looked at several solutions for questions similar to mine, and I believe the problem is due to file/directory permissions and ownership.  I understand how to set file permissions/ownership, however I am not sure exactly what permissions need to be set, or what files they should be set on in order to get the app to work correctly.  I've included several pieces of info below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As a note, the www-data group contains the users ubuntu and www-data.

**Permissions and code for service file**

```
/etc/systemd/system/app.service
- rxw rwx r--    root    www-data

[Unit]
Description=App

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/node/website.com/app.js
Restart=always
DynamicUser=yes
User=ubuntu
Group=nogroup
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/home/node/website.com

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Permissions for all Apache files in /etc/apache2**

```
rwx rwx r--    ubuntu    www-data
```

**Permissions and code for website.com.conf**

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/website.com.conf
- rwx rwx r--    ubuntu    www-data

<virtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email.email.com
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias *.website.com
    
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full

    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</virtualHost>
```

**Permissions for website directory and app.js file**

```
/home/node/website.com
d rwx rwx r--    ubuntu    www-data

/home/node/website.com/app.js
- rwx rwx rwx    ubuntu    www-data
```

**Permissions for sqlite3 database directory and file**

```
/mnt/db-drive/data/sqlite3/website
d rwx rwx rw    www-data    www-data

/mnt/db-drive/data/sqlite3/website/website.db
- rwx rwx rw-    www-data    www-data
```

Comment: Can you write normal files on USB drive? ex, `touch /mnt/db-drive/data/sqlite3/website/testfile`

Comment: @pierpy Yes.  I can also write to the .db file if I run app.js from the console with 'node app.js' as the ubuntu user.  I just can't write to the db file when running app.js from the app.service file.

Comment: What happens changing `User=ubuntu` in  `User=www-data`?

Comment: @pierpy I received a new error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to figure out a solution using the app.service file.  I instead used [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) as my daemon process manager and writing to the database worked fine.